# Securing a modem - computer connection

Tags: router

I'd like to connect a pc directly to a dsl modem.
I know that routers can be hacked and e.g. DNS requests can be redirected. But what can be done to hack a modem (without a router!) and what can I do to prevent these attacks? I also read (though without any references) that a router provides more security compared to a modem because of NATing. Are there any more security benefits of a router? And does this outweigh the additional attack surface from the router firmware? 
If I go without a router do I need to invest more in the security of the directly attached computer instead?

Comment: There is a lot of material on this exact topic on the Internet. Have you done any reading or research? As it stands, answers will simply point you to external resources.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not the modem isn't usually the attack vector because they often need physical access to be hacked. A wireless router is usually the attack vector because it opens itself up. If you're going to be the safest you can, you'd get a router(either wireless or wired) and put it between you and the computer. These extra jump steps make it harder for people t find your computer without knowing the exact configuration and often make you safer. To make it the safest you can get though I'd suggest a firewalled router, and if it is wireless and you don't need the wireless, *turning off wireless*. This is usually the best practice to protect a single wired connection in a residential environment.

Of course you could also go the extra mile and set up your own PF-sense box and just connect to that from your modem to your computer. But at that point you're literally building a router.